# NetBeans goes very slow

Tags: performance, tomcat, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1. I have a web application in JSP using Spring version 3.0.2 and Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA. Slowly and gradually, it has been growing in size yet it's not a very big application though I have added many external class libraries as and when required like [`HibernateValidator`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc).

The performance is degraded and it takes a considerable amount of time in building the application. When changes are saved, many a times, the application is deployed infinitely/endlessly with the auto-deploy feature of NetBeans. It never ends and I have to restart the IDE and the procedure begins all over again from scratch. Sometimes the application is stopped automatically and I have to restart the Tomcat server (6.0.26) because mostly an attempt to restart the application doesn't succeed.

Many a times (every half an hour or so), the application ends with following exception.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen Space

and I have to restart the system itself!

While working with JPA along with EJB and JSF as a front-end (GlassFish Server 3), it **often** wasn't the case even with heavily loaded applications with the same version of the NetBeans IDE and exactly the same platform, if I remember correctly.

Are there some ways to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try overriding the jvm option for more memory if you can

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=756m"
```

here http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/projects/THREDDS/tech/tds4.2/reference/JavaOptsSummary.html you can find a bit more about java_opts parameters

Comment: That link says, "*You can set JAVA_OPTS in the ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh file.*" but I can't see the `setenv.sh` file in my *bin* directory - `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin`. It's Microsoft Windows XP, Professional version 2002, Service Pack 3.

Comment: The link was more for explaining each of the params. On windows and to set the memory settings globally for your jvms, try setting the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable with -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=756m (possibly replacing the values for numbers that may suit you better). I havent tried setting specifically for netbeans, as I use eclipse, but apparently you can set the same variables on your launcher http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/

Comment: According to that link, I have changed `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"` in my C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9.1\etc\netbeans.conf file.

Comment: to `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms128m -J-XX:PermSize=512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=756m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"` and the performance has increased significantly.

Comment: Also enabled this switch - `-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled`. When the heap size (-Xmx) is explicitly specified, this switch is required to be enabled so that the JVM can use different algorithms for major garbage collection events as specified.

Comment: One thing however, still remains as mentioned in the question. When a file(s) is saved it is automatically deployed by the auto-deploy feature of the IDE but sometimes (not always), the deployment process (as indicated by a progress bar) at the bottom-right corner of the IDE can be seen as it is going endlessly like an infinite loop (yet being deployed even though seemingly, it has already been deployed). It never ends, once happens. Why does this happen? Do you know? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are using Netbeans. A simple solution would be to go tools->servers -> (selecte the server (in your case tomcat))->platform, then in the VM option, paste this settings:

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

that would solve your problem. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My NetBeans is performing well with these settings I made.