# facing perm gen space error in weblogic

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weblogic

I am new to weblogic.
After starting the server when i see administrator console and get log-in it throws below exception.

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:288)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I did lot of google and found some solution to initialize `JAVA_OPTIONS` like `-XX:xmx` and etc.
I tried to set this in `startdomainenv.cmd` file but with no luck.

Please help.
Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13428920/1037210).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To set **PermGen** size you can use e.g. `-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.

Regarding **Weblogic**, set the JAVA_OPTIONS and see if these options are properly passed in as parameters into your Java process. You can also directly set these parameters in the `startWeblogic.cmd` script.

To check that your `JAVA_OPTIONS` are set properly, add `echo %JAVA_OPTIONS%` into the `startWeblogic.cmd` script and see the output. Also, you can use e.g. **jConsole**, **jstat**, or **jmap** to monitor Heap usage of the Weblogic process at runtime. This will show you the sizes and occupation of the **PermGen**.

Comment: This works, just be careful as the JAVA_OPTIONS will effect all of java on your machine that may utilize this system variable. If the problem is specific to Weblogic, alter the setDomainEnv.cmd as Dileep points out. I only mention this because I set this variable to get it working, only to cause issues with my other java versions for other code efforts.

Answer (score 7):

You can try by changing the memory settings of weblogic in your server.
* Go to - 
`<weblogic path>\Middleware\user_projects\domains\fms_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd`
* Open the file
* Change the settings

```
if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
) else (
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
)
```

Change these settings as per your requirement and environment.

Answer (score 3):

to complete the reponse of user267 you must change also :
set MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_64BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

set MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_32BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to edit the `DOMAIN\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd` file. The following modifications were made before the server would start as intended:

- The `-Xms` and `-Xmx` values were increased
- the `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` values were increased too

and lastly, but probably most importantly

- the `if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (` conditions were changed to `if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Oracle" (` in order to properly recognize my JVM.

Before this last modification the memory changes were only partly reflected to the initialised JVM, and this meant that the parameters regarding the PermGen Space were simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share what solved the problem for me:
I sourced setDomainEnv.sh and echo ${JAVA_OPTIONS} and noticed that the MEM arguments were not there.

So I added MEM_ARGS to the last setup of the JAVA_OPTIONS.

Like so:
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${MEM_ARGS}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS

Cheers