# I am not able to start weblogic server

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am using weblogic to deploy the java project. when I am trying to start the weblogic server I am getting following error. kindly guide me in this.

**weblogic.application.utils.StateChangeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Per
mGen space..**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944778/facing-perm-gen-space-error-in-weblogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the HEAP of your weblogic instance, probaby in your setDomainEnv.sh

-Xms256m -Xmx512m